# Trick OS X into thinking it has a Retina display?

Tags: macos, resolution, display

I own a Wacom Cintiq 13' display/input device. It connects via HDMI to my Mac Pro and works nice so far, except that all the menus, buttons and controls in OS X are very tiny. A resolution of 1920x1080 on a 13' display results in quite a high dpi. It's very straining to the eyes.

The obvious way to "solve" this is to go to the Settings > Display and select "Scaled" and choose a lower resolution. Everything would be larger, of course, but at the expense of sacrificing the resolution. I basically want to keep the resolution at 1920x1080 but just change the scaling factor for UI controls.

That's more or less exactly what OS X does when it sees a retina display. I wondered if anybody of you figured out if we can trick OS X into thinking it has a retina display?